# Retrieving .csv file written by docker python program

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to access the .csv file which my dockerized python program is making.

Here is my docker file:

```html
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.7

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /BotCloud

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /BotCloud

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

RUN wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
  tar -xvzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
  cd ta-lib/ && \
  ./configure --prefix=/usr && \
  make && \
  make install

RUN rm -R ta-lib ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz

RUN pip install ta-lib

# Run BotFinal.py when the container launches
CMD ["python","-u", "BotLiveSnake.py"]
```

Here is the code snippet that is in my python file BotSnakeLive.py

```html
def write(string):
    with open('outfile.csv','w') as f:
        f.write(string)
        f.write("\n")
write(str("Starting Time: "+datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(df.tail(1)['Open Time'])/10**3).strftime('%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%SUTC'))+",Trading:"+str(pairing)+",Starting Money:"+str(money)+",SLpercent:"+str(SLpercent)+",TPpercent,"+str(TPpercent))
```

Running my python program locally, outfile.csv is created in the same folder as my python program. However, with docker, I'm not sure where this outfile ends up. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it not written to `/BotCloud/outfile.csv`?

Comment: Just a quick check -
CMD ["python","-u", "BotLiveSnake.py"] & your code snippet file has different name
If you need to retrieve out the .csv from within the container to the host you need to define a VOLUME /BotCloud & on docker run mount this volume on to your host docker run -v /some/folder/onhost:/BotCloud <yourimage>

Comment: @Ross What is the command I use in order to access that? I'm not sure how to check if it is there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In general, references to file paths that don't start with `/` are always interpreted relative to the current working directory.  Unless you've changed that somehow (`os.chdir`, an entrypoint script running `cd`, the `docker run -w` option) that will be the `WORKDIR` you declared in the `Dockerfile`.

So: your file should be in `/BotCloud/outfile.csv`, *in the container's filesystem space*.

Note that containers have their own isolated filesystem space that is destroyed when the container is deleted.  If the primary way your application communicates is via files, it may be much easier to use a non-Docker mechanism, such as Python virtual environments, to isolate your application from the rest of the system.  You can mount a host directory into the container with `docker run -v`, or `docker cp` files out.  (Note with `docker run -v` in particular it is helpful if the data is written to someplace that *isn't* the same directory as your application.)